# How do you determine the hazard rate function for a uniformly distributed variable X ~ Uni(0,a)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have a uniformly distributed variable X ~ Uni(0,a).  Then the probability density function

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{a} & \text{ if } 0 <x < a \\ 0 & \text{ else }\end{cases}$$

and the cumulative distribution function

$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } x \leq0 \\ \frac{x}{a} & \text{ 0 < x< a } \\ 1 & x \geq a \end{cases}$$

The formula for the hazard rate function is:

$\lambda_X(t)= \frac{f_X(t)}{1-F_X(t)} = $

$$ \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } x \leq0 \\ \frac{1}{a-x} & \text{ 0 < x< a } \\ \frac{0}{1-1} & x \geq a \end{cases}$$

The part that I'm confused about is the last case $x \geq a$ of the hazard rate function because I'm getting a divide by zero error.  How do I correct this?

Comment: Note that as $x \to a$, the hazard rate is increasing without bound towards $\infty$. This is standard for all random variables with bounded support. So there is nothing to correct. In fact, I am surprised that you don't get a "divide-by-zero" error for values of $x$ very close to $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't correct that.

The hazard function is indeed undefined above the supremum for the random variable's support.